# Invert the last byte of a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I'd like to test my hashing program by inverting a single byte at the end of a file without modifying the timestamp. Keeping the timestamp from changing is easy enough, but how do I use a unix utility to invert the last byte of the file?

For example: xor the last byte with 0xFF (an operation that's easily reversible)

Comment: Is this a "text" file or a "binary" file?

Comment: @glennjackman It should work on both of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself in python:

```
python3 -c "import os, sys; name = sys.argv[1]; info = os.stat(name); f=open(sys.argv[1], 'rb+'); f.seek(-1,2); b = f.read(1)[0] ^ 0xFF; f.seek(-1,2); f.write(bytes([b])); print('Writing:', bytes([b])); os.utime(name, (info.st_atime, info.st_mtime))" filename
```

Not the most elegant solution, but I'm sure you guys have some ingenious sed trick and can do it better.

Here's is the full version, you can run with ./invert.py (filename)

```
import os, sys

name = sys.argv[1]
info = os.stat(name)

with open(name, 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(-1,2)
    b = f.read(1)[0] ^ 0xFF
    f.seek(-1,2)
    f.write(bytes([b]))
    print('Writing:', bytes([b]))
    os.utime(name, (info.st_atime, info.st_mtime))
```

Comment: newlines are free, please use a few of them.

Comment: @glennjackman I wanted a one liner I could run in the terminal. This works. If it bothers you, feel free to replace each semicolon with a newline and save it to a file.

Comment: Alternatively, post this one-liner and an expanded version that's easier to read and understand.

Comment: Sure thing @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 2):

Not sed, but this seems to work in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/.\z/ $& ^ "\xff" /es if eof'  < in > out
```

It reads by lines, but that doesn't matter since it's 8-bit clean. `eof` is true on the last line, and `\z` matches at the raw end of the string (`$` would also match before an optional final newline, so not strictly the last byte). The replacement is just the xor operation on the matched string.

Comment: Nice answer, but reading the entire file would be slow for larger files. It also needs to be piped into /dev/null or it will fill the terminal with nonsense bytes.

Comment: @Benjamin, this answer does not overwrite the source file. redirecting to /dev/null would throw away the changed last line.

Comment: @Benjamin, oh, sure, it's just that sed and Perl make it really easy to loop over full files like that, and you did suggest sed ;) Like glenn said, don't redirect to `/dev/null` but to where ever you want the modified data to go. Or use `perl -i` to modify the file in-place (it still reads and rewrites it, though).

Answer (score 1):

Tools like `sed` and `awk` are generally not suited to seeking files, or handle a file's content at the byte level. They are line-oriented, want regexps or line-numbers as addresses, and have no (builtin) way to retrieve a file's metadata like e.g. its size or timestamps.

It is possible to achieve your intended result through command-line tools too but, as far as I can conceive, you need to perform "glue" operations in any case.

Here is my attempt, just for fun: (*on a single line only for demonstration, as per your wish*)

```bash
(set -e -- $(ls -l <file>); pos=$(($5 - 1)); asciicode=$(od -j "$pos" -t u1 -A n "$9"); invcode=$(printf '%02x' $((asciicode ^ 0xff))); printf "\\x${invcode}" | dd of="$9" obs="$pos" seek=1)
```

Replace `<file>` with your file's name.

Not really a one-liner, as you can see. I've gone to some extents to be POSIX compliant, but even without that it wouldn't be much shorter.

Note also that it does not take care of the file's timestamp. To do that with command-line tools it'd become like: (*this time broken down for readability and explanation*)

```bash
(
set -e -- $(ls -l <file>)  # <-- parsing 'ls' output generally is not a good move
pos=$(($5 - 1))            # file's size from `ls -l`, minus 1 to point to last byte
asciicode=$(od -j "$pos" -t u1 -A n "$9")  # 'od' can seek with '-j' option
invcode=$(printf '%02x' $((asciicode ^ 0xff)))  # 8-bit value read by 'od' xor-ed
                                                # and made a 0-padded 2-digits hex value
temp="$(mktemp)"                               # temporary helper file
trap 'rm -f "$temp"' EXIT                      # dispose of it in due time
touch -r "$9" "$temp"                          # copy original file's timestamp
printf "\\x${invcode}" | dd of="$9" obs="$pos" seek=1  # put computed 8-bit value in place
touch -r "$temp" "$9"                          # restore file's timestamp
)
```

Using `touch -r` back and forth on a temp file because that should be the most portable way to maintain nanosecond precision.

It may be good noting also the necessity to perform the risky operation of parsing `ls` output, but I can't think of another POSIX tool to retrieve a file's size. Of course in this case it could be done in a safer way (complicating the script even more), but this necessity may be one more hint that we're stretching standard tools a bit beyond their intended tasks.